# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string

Tags: java, user-interface, exception

```
package semester2;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
      
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your name");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Hello " + name);
      
    int age =
      Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your age"));
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You are " + age + " years old");
      
    double height =
      Double.parseDouble (JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your height"));
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You are " + height + " cm tall");
      
  }
}
```

[These are the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5SA7.png)

IDK what happened I am new to java and not familiar with these types of errors...

Comment: What does doing a quick search on that error bring to you? Did you try?

Comment: @esQmo_ i am literally trying to fix these errors for 3 days.....if you know the answer than help me

Comment: This is your full code? I've tested here and it works!

Comment: u tested it in what IDE ?

Comment: Eclipse Version 2023-06

Comment: The goal is not to for us to fix your issue but to help you fix it yourself so that you can learn. I know it can be tough but it worth it.

Comment: @DiegoBorba I'm using that eclipse version too..anyways that new code by you is working & that my old code is working in VS code

Comment: The problem are in the java version I gess... What java version are you using?

Comment: The code is working. You get the exception when you dont fiil in age when promted

Comment: @esQmo_ I don't think so, when you dont fiil in age it returns a empty string and not null.

Comment: Always add a tag for your particular Java GUI framework, as we have several in Java (JavaFX, Swing, SWT, Vaadin, etc.). In this case, Swing. I did so for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

The exception you see means that the method `Ìnteger.parseInt()` complains having to parse an unsuitable string (null). That null must have come from `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)`.

When you look into the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object)) it does not mention that showInputDialog() can return null. But it also does not specify what happens if the user

- enters data and presses Ok
- enters no data and presses Ok
- enters or not data and presses Cancel

While the null value might indicate the user pressed Cancel (we still don't know), your code needs to deal with that situation. Either check for `null` before calling `parseInt()`, or call `parseInt()` regardless, catch the `NumberFormatException` and react in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... IDK what happened I am new to java and not familiar with these types of errors... "*

If you cancel the *age* input dialog it will return *null*.
And, passing a *null* argument to *[Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))* will produce a *[NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)*.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Cannot parse null string
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:781)
    at test.main(test.java:13)
```

Here is the source for *Integer#parseInt*.
*[GitHub – jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L623)*.

```java
public static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
            throws NumberFormatException
{
    /* ... */

    if (s == null) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Cannot parse null string");
    }

    ...
```

You'll need to check for *null*.
I suggest using the *Integer* and *Double* classes, you can utilize the *null* assignment.

```java
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your name");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Hello " + name);

Integer age = null;
String string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your age");
if (string != null && !string.isBlank()) age = Integer.valueOf(string);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You are " + age + " years old");

Double height = null;
string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter your height");
if (string != null && !string.isBlank()) height = Double.valueOf(string);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You are " + height + " cm tall");
```

Here is the the tutorial on *Java Dialogs*.
*[How to Make Dialogs (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With Swing > Using Swing Components)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)*.

Comment: Just the input not being null and not emtpy does not guarantee it can be parsed as Integer.

Answer (score 0):

So now you know the deal. To simply recap, the [Integer.parseInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) method can only accept a string consisting of *one* or *more* digits from **0** to **9** *(no spaces at all)* but, only up to [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-integermaxvalue) which happens to be `2147483647` OR [Integer.MIN_VALUE](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-integerminvalue-in-java) which happens to be `-2147483648`. Yes, there are two specific characters the [Integer.parseInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) method will accept and they are the *plus* (**+**) character (which basically indicates an *unsigned*, positive value and is rarely used) and the **minus** (*-*) character which indicates a *signed* (negative) value.

If there are any alpha characters within the argument passed to the [Integer.parseInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) method (including any white-spaces) other than `+` or `-`, then the method will fail with a [NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html).

The [Double.parseDouble()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_parsedouble.htm) method works in very much the same fashion however, it does accept more alpha characters, for example:

- `.` Decimal Point (period)       {only after the whole number portion
  of the string: `"234.342"`);
- `+` Unsigned designator          (only at the beginning of the
  string: `"+234.342"`);
- `-` Signed designator            (only at the beginning of the
  string: `"-234.342"`);
- `d` or `D` Double Type indicator (only at the end of the string: `"234.342D"`);
- `f` or `F` Float Type indicator  (only at the end of the string: `"234.342F"`);
- `e` or `E` Exponent Notation     (only within the decimal portion of
  the string: `"234.34E2"`);

And, you can also supply a string representation of an Integer value (whole number) to this method and it will convert it to Double Type, for example:

```
double dblValue = Double.parseDouble("234");
```

The `dbleValue` variable will hold: `234.0`

As already explained to you, the Input Dialog will return `null` when the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button is selected or the dialog window is closed with the <kbd>X</kbd> button in the upper-right corner. Obviously, this needs to be dealt with and the best way to that is to **validate** the data you receive from the User. If the User makes a mistake then, inform that User and let him or her try again on the same prompt. Each bit of data entry provided from the User should be validated so to eliminate problems down the road. Deal with those problems at the entry level.

Here is a runnable example. Be sure to read the comments in code. It looks like a lot of code but, if you delete all the commenting...it really isn't. Try it out if you like:

```
public class Test {
    
    // Class member variables:
    private final javax.swing.JFrame parent = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        {
            parent.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            parent.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double height;


    // Application entry point:
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This app takes no Command-Line arguments.

        /* App started this way to avoid the need for 
           statics (unless we really want them):          */
        new Test().startApp(args);
    }

    /* Code pertinent to this application is run here 
       and is initially called from the `main()` method: */
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Outer Loop...Continues looping until User is happy with the entries:
        int yesNo = 1; // Used in final JOptionPane Confirm Dialog:
        while (yesNo != 0) {
            // Initialize class member variables upon every iteration of the outer loop:
            name = "";
            age = 0;
            height = 0.0d;
        
            // PROMPT #1:
            /* Name...If nothing is supplied the app ends (inner loop).
               While name is empty...keep looping:            */
            while (name.isEmpty()) {
                // Get User's input:
                name = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent,
                        "<html><b>Please enter your name:</b><br>"
                        + "<font size='2' color=gray>If you enter nothing, this "
                        + "application will close.</font><br><br></html>",
                        "Your Name?", javax.swing.JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                
                // VALIDATION:
                // If null or empty string is returned from dialog then end application:
                if (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    quit(); // Release the JFrame (parent) resource.
                    return;
                }
                /* If there are numerical digits within the name then 
                   inform the User and allow to try again. Digits are
                   not allowed in name for this particular case:   */
                else if (name.matches(".*[0-9].*") || name.matches(".*?\\p{Punct}.*?")) {
                    // Inform of Invalid Entry...
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "<html><center>Invalid Name Supplied!</center>"
                            + "<center><font size='5' color=red><b>" + name + "</b></font>"
                            + "</center>There can be no numerical digits or special<br> characters in your name! "
                            + "Select <b>OK</b> to try<br>again...<br><br></html>", "Invalid Name!",
                            javax.swing.JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    name = "";  // Empty name to ensure re-loop:
                }
            }
            // If we've made it here the 'name' validation has passed.

            
            // PROMPT #2:
            /* Age...Continue looping until a valid age is supplied:
               If nothing is supplied then the application ends:
               Allowable age range is from 1 to 120 years (inclusive): */
            String theAge = "";
            while (theAge.isEmpty()) {
                // Get User's input:
                theAge = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent,
                        "<html>Hello <font color=blue><b>" + name + "</b></font>, "
                        + "now please enter your age:<br><br></html>", "Your Age?",
                        javax.swing.JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                
                // VALIDATION:
                /* If Nothing was supplied or the Cancel or close 
                   buttons were selected then quit.           */
                if (theAge == null || theAge.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    quit();     // Release the JFrame (parent) resource.
                    return;     // Simply returning effectively ends this appliction.
                }
                // If the User's entry all digits?
                else if (!theAge.matches("\\d+")) {
                    // No...Inform User and allow to try again:
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "<html><center>You Have supplied An Invalid Age!</center>"
                            + "<center><font size='5' color=red><b>" + theAge + "</b></font>"
                            + "</center>Your age must contain numerical digits relating to an<br>"
                            + "inclusive integer value from 1 (min) to 120 (max)!<br><br>"
                            + "Select the <b>OK</b> button to try again...<br><br></html>", "Invalid Age!",
                            javax.swing.JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    theAge = "";  // Empty name to ensure proper re-loop:
                    continue;
                }
                
                // Convert input to int:
                age = Integer.parseInt(theAge);
                
                // Is 'age' within a desire range? (1 to 120 years)
                if (age < 1 || age > 120) {
                    // No...Inform User and allow to try again...
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "<html><center>You Have supplied An Invalid Age!</center>"
                            + "<center><font size='5' color=red><b>" + theAge + "</b></font>"
                            + "</center>Your age must a value from 1 (min) to 120 (max)!<br>"
                            + "Select OK to try again...<br><br></html>", "Invalid Age!",
                            javax.swing.JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    theAge = "";  // Empty name to ensure re-loop:
                    age = 0;      // Make sure 'age' is reset to 0:
                }
            }
            // If we've made it here the `age` validation has passed.

            
            // PROMPT #3:
            /* Height...Continue looping until a valid height is supplied:
               Hieght range is from 8 inches to 102 inches:            */
            String theHeight = "";
            while (theHeight.isEmpty()) {
                // Get User's input:
                theHeight = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent,
                        "<html>Well <font color=blue><b>" + name + "</b></font>, we know "
                        + "your name and we know that you are<br><font color=blue><b>"
                        + age + "</b></font> years old but, we still yet need to know "
                        + "your height.<br><br>Please supply your height in inches:<br><br></html>",
                        "Your Height?", javax.swing.JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                
                /* If Nothing was supplied or the Cancel or close 
                   buttons were selected then quit.           */
                if (theHeight == null || theHeight.trim().isEmpty() || !theHeight.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                    quit();     // Release the JFrame (parent) resource.
                    return;
                }
                
                // Convert input to double type:
                height = Double.parseDouble(theHeight);

                // Is 'height' within a desire range? (8 to 102 inches)
                if (height < 8.0d || height > 102.0d) {
                    // No...inform User and allow to retry:
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "<html><center>You Have supplied An Invalid Height!</center>"
                            + "<center><font size='5' color=red><b>" + theHeight + "</b></font>"
                            + "</center>Your height must a value from 8.0 (min) to 102.0 (max)!<br>"
                            + "Select OK to try again...<br><br></html>", "Invalid Height!",
                            javax.swing.JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    theHeight = "";     // Empty name to ensure re-loop:
                    height = 0.0d;      // Reset 'height' to 0.0 (height is a double value):
                }
            }
            // If we've made it here the `age` validation has passed.
            
            
            // FINAL PROMPT - DISPLAY:
            /* Display Results...If User selects anything other than YES
               then he/she is allowed to re-enter all the data otherwise
               the application ends:                        :      */
            yesNo = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent,
                    "<html>"
                    + "So, overall, the information you provided is:<br>"
                    + "<ul>"
                    + "• <b>Name:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=blue>" + name + "</font><br>"
                    + "• <b>Age:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=red>" + age + "</font> years<br>"
                    + "• <b>Height:</b> <font color=purple>" + height + "</font> inches<br>"
                    + "</ul>"
                    + "Is this correct?<br><br></html>",
                    "Confirm your Input:", javax.swing.JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

        // YES WAS SELECTED SO QUIT:
        /* Release the JFrame (parent) resource and, display 
          a Notification Box in the bottom-right corner of 
          your screen, that you have quit:               */
        quit();
        
        // DONE
    }
    
    /* Quits the Application:    */
    private void quit() { 
        // Dispose of the JFrame used as parent for all the dialogs:
        parent.dispose();
        // Display a Quit Notification:
        sendNotification("Quiting Demo Application!", "Bye Bye For Now. Try it "
                       + "again later.", java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE);
    }
    
    /**
     * Displays a typical Windows Notification above the Taskbar. If a
     * SystemTray is not supported within the system this method was called then
     * nothing is displayed (the method is not processed).<br>
     *
     * @param title           (String) Message Title<br>
     *
     * @param message         (String) Message<br>
     *
     * @param messageTypeIcon (MessageType) The MessageType is a ENUM from the
     *                        TrayIncon Class, for example: TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO<pre>
     *  The different MessageTypes available are:
     *
     *      TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR
     *      TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO
     *      TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE
     *      TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING</pre>
     */
    private void sendNotification(String title, String message, java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType messageTypeIcon) {
        try {
            //Obtain only one instance of the SystemTray object
            java.awt.SystemTray tray = java.awt.SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            if (!java.awt.SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                return;
            }
            java.awt.Image image = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("");
            java.awt.TrayIcon trayIcon = new java.awt.TrayIcon(image, "");
            tray.add(trayIcon);
            
            trayIcon.displayMessage(title, message, messageTypeIcon);
            tray.remove(trayIcon);
        }
        catch (java.awt.AWTException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```